# why glGenerateMipmap makes no difference?

Tags: opengl

I have a texture of size(720,1080),and I want to use `glGenerateMipmap` to generate 4 mipmaps.My codes are:

```
    float* texture = new float......
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, 720, 1080, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL,0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 3);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

I didn't see any differences when magnify or minify the texture, where I am wrong?

Comment: "*`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR`*" That's not allowed. There's no such thing as magnification mipmapping.

Comment: Thank you ,and I use GL_LINEAR for GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, but I still see heavy moire effect as the same.Is there any way to improve this defect?

Comment: Use [Anisotropic filtering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Anisotropic_filtering). e.g.: `glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY, 8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is not a valid value for the texture parameter `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`. Valid values are `GL_NEAREST` and `GL_LINEAR`.
Anyway, to get ride of [Moire effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) i suggest using [Anisotropic filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering) (alos see [Sampler Object - Anisotropic filtering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_Object#Anisotropic_filtering)). e.g.:

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY, 8);
```